# Can I Limit a user's permissions in SQL Server 2008 or C# at runtime?

Tags: security, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net, permissions

I have a website that I'm working on, and its hosted on a shared hosting site that gives me 1 database connection.

Of course, that login has full access to read and write (as it is the connection I use to build my tables, etc).

However, I want to allow users to be able to write ad-hoc SQL queries, but I want to limit them severely... as an **example**, not being able to write to any tables.

So my question is - is there ANY way to limit ANY functionality at all at runtime... perhaps as a setting passed in the connection string?

Or is there something I can do in C#? (example: I can start a transaction and roll it back)?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't create new user accounts for each user? Then use the built in server security to limit what each user can do.

You could, for example, set up role groups for the new limited users, and then use table security to limit access.

```
grant select on my_table to limited_user_group
deny insert, update, delete on my_table to limited_user_group
```

Comment: Yes, the reason is that the site is "hosted on a shared hosting site that gives me 1 database connection." I don't have access to those types of administrative functions.

Comment: @Timothy that doesn't necessarily imply no ability to create users, though. In that case I guess my answer is "get better hosting".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) t-sql statement to switch the execution context for the session to another user. You can use WITH COOKIE to lock the execution context down until you supply the cookie value with your REVERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you cannot limit access to the very same user that you are... so what I'm doing as a workaround is I've created another database (a blank one) and I'm going to wrap all of the user queries in a transaction that I will force to rollback.

It's a yucky solution, but as Factor Mystic said in his comment - "get better hosting" is probably the best solution (meaning - the problem here lies with the hosting company).

Comment: Your method won't necessarily work. If the users code has `WHILE (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) COMMIT` then it will be committed already before the rollback statement is reached.

Comment: But even if you can't create new server logins I reckon that creating new database users will likely work then you can use `EXECUTE AS user`

Comment: Maybe not actually. You would need to do `CREATE USER limiteduser FOR CERTIFICATE ` but `EXECUTE AS user ` doesn't appear to work for these.

Comment: I agree... I don't think there is a *correct* way (or 100% way) of doing this without actually creating a new user - I'll just have to contact my hosting company.